# PHP using class properties inside class

Tags: php

I'm a bit confused by PHP. In the example below the only accepted way is to initialise bVar in the constructor. Do i always have to do this if i want to use class properties inside the class itself? Or is my syntax just bad for the purpose if accessing class properties within the class itself?

```
class test{
protected aVar = "varValue";
protected bVar;
function __construct(){
    $this->bVar = "varValue";
}

function testerFunc(){
    echo $aVar //undefined variable
    echo $this->$aVar //undefined variable
    echo $bvar //works fine
}


}
```

Comment: I can't imagine that `echo $bvar` works. If you want to access this variable you have to call it like this: `$this->bVar`

Comment: You have a typo where you're trying to echo $aVar. It should be `echo $this->aVar;` Remove the dollar sign before the variable name.

Comment: Variables in PHP are represented by a dollar sign followed by the name of the variable!

Comment: As RainDev says, you also need a dollar sign when you declare the variable in the first place: `protected $aVar = "varValue";`

Comment: Also, all your echo statements lack semicolons.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is bit of a mess:

```php
class test {
    protected $aVar = "varValue";
    protected $bVar;

    function __construct() {
        $this->bVar = "varValue";
    }

    function testerFunc() {
        echo $aVar; //undefined variable
        echo $this->aVar; // varValue (works fine)
        echo $this->bVar; // varValue (works fine)
        echo $bvar; //undefined variable
    }
}
```